# Database Design With Multiple Payment Methods And Membership Types

Tags: database-design

I want to design my database similarly to something like this: [Better way to design payment database with multiple payment methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57510457/better-way-to-design-payment-database-with-multiple-payment-methods)

But my database is a little more complex where instead of buying 1 off items, customers are buying monthly/yearly memberships to access services on the website. Stripe payments are recurring subscriptions while btcpayserver cryptocurrency payments are made only 1 time and are not recurring subscriptions.

When a customer buys either a monthly/yearly membership, the subscription table active column becomes 1 (true) and the UserMembership membership column becomes either monthly/yearly depending on what membership the customer buys. If a customer switches back and forth between payment methods every month/year, new records are not added and instead existing records will be updated with the new data for that user.

The problem with my current setup is that when a cryptocurrency payment is made, there will be NULL columns where Stripe API data goes (Stripe customer id, Stripe subscription id, Stripe price id) or there will be previous existing stripe data if the user makes a stripe payment then a cryptocurrency payment.

All I want to know is how to best design this database, if any additional tables should be created, and where to put some of the columns so that there will be no NULL columns anywhere. I am open to a complete redesign if necessary since the database is not in production yet.

Should I make a separate stripe table containing all of the stripe API ids? Should I only have 1 amount column in the Membership table and not in the Stripe and Btcpayserver tables?

If I add more payment methods in the future, I want to be sure the database can handle that for this type of business model.

Current database:

```
Membership table (pricing plans):
Membership_table_id PK
Slug - name of the website's plans on the pricing page (e.g. Pro, Enterprise)
Type - what kind of recurring payment is it - Free, Monthly, Yearly
Amount - how much the plan costs in USD
Price Id - (comes from stripe API)
​
Stripe UserMembership table (customers and their current assigned memberships):
UserMembership_table_id PK
Username FK
Stripe customer id (comes from stripe API)
Membership - free, monthly, yearly (the membership plan a customer paid for and currently has with the website)
​
Stripe Subscriptions table (customers and their stripe subscription ids and if those subscription ids are active/inactive):
Subscription_table_id PK
Username FK
Stripe subscription id - (comes from stripe API)
Active (boolean) - if the customer has an active/inactive subscription
​
Stripe Cancel table (customer cancel reasons and when they cancel):
Cancel_table_id PK
Username FK
Cancel reason
Date of cancel
Stripe customer id - (comes from stripe API)
​
Btcpay table:
Btcpay_table_id PK
Username FK
amount - how much the customer paid in USD
invoice_id - (comes from the Btcpay API)
order_date - date the customer made a payment or when the invoice completely settles
```

Possible solution?

```
Membership table:
Membership_table_id PK
Slug
Type - free, monthly, yearly
Amount
​
UserMembership:
UserMembership_table_id PK
Username FK
Membership - free, monthly, yearly
​
Subscriptions table:
Subscription_table_id PK
Username FK
Active (boolean)
​
Cancel table:
Cancel_table_id PK
Username FK
Cancel reason
Date of cancel

Btcpay table:
Btcpay_table_id PK
Username FK
order_date
invoice_id (comes from btcpayserver API)
​
Stripe table:
Username FK
Stripe customer id (comes from stripe API)
Stripe subscription id (comes from stripe API)
Stripe price id (comes from stripe API)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a dupe

Comment: @mustaccio I decided to make both because I want to put it in the place(s) that allow me to get more traffic to this question. If the question remains here in dba stackexchange, will there be less traffic to it? If so, I'd rather put it on Stackoverflow and delete the question here.

Comment: the moderators on Stack Overflow migrated the question to DBA, with the reason that this is more suitable for DBA than the main Stack Overflow. Since you had cross-posted on both sites, there are now duplicates here, and one will need to be closed. Generally, "How should I design my database?" questions are a better fit for DBA, rather than SO, since SO focuses on coding/querying questions.

Comment: @AMtwo Ok no problem. I am fine with you closing one of them. If you need me to do anything like delete and recreate the question again, let me know. I hope that you or someone else could help me figure this out.

Comment: You can always delete your own question (or both).